# Type error on merged cells in Excel for display message ability

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA code in Excel that allows me to view the contents of a cell when I select it. Here's an example:

[image: Example of cell selection]

Here is the code for this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
With Selection.Validation
.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
:=xlBetween
.InputMessage = Target.Text
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
.ShowInput = True
.ShowError = True
End With
End Sub
```

However, when I select a merged cell, I am getting the following error:

[image: Error message]

How can I run this code to work on merged cells?

Comment: Can you hit the debug button and see what the values are for Target and Target.Text (if it exists) for that cell? And anything else that looks relevant! Are you in the first cell in the merged range, or one of the cells that have been merged? What behaviour do you want here - nothing, or the text from the first cell?

Comment: @Rup Target.Text = Null, the error happens in any part of the merged cells but I want it to display the contents of the cell no matter what cell is selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.InputMessage = Target.Text` is giving the error. The problem is that the target is multiple cells and these do not have the property `Text`. A quick fix would be to take the first cell of the target:

```
.InputMessage = Target.Cells(1).Text
```

Thus, if it is a single cell it is still the first one and if it is merged, it works ok:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween
        .InputMessage = Target.Cells(1).Text
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working on most cells.. but on one merged cell I am now getting a '1004' Application -defined or object-defined error - any ideas?

Comment: @Vityata type 64 when i type check it

Comment: @codeman - simply writing 64 inside the cell? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Vityata, data type 64 refers to an array of values....I guess that is what is meant.

Comment: @JvdV - so what should be written inside the cell to produce 1004 error?

Comment: the value of this particular cell is referenced from another cell on another sheet in the workbook (also a merged cell) - which I am guessing is giving the cell a strange data type...

Comment: @Vityata, I'm not sure myself either. Maybe a listbox? Either way, merged cells are a nightmare :(. So many nasty side-effects to keep in mind. Your solution is as good as it gets IMO.